# Unable parse data from web service and print in listview in android

Tags: android

I am trying parse data from web-service to print in a `ListView`. I am able to get the data and bind the list, but am receiving a `NullPointerException` in my `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExcute()` method at the line `fruitlist.setadapter(list)` but I don't see why. Here is the stack trace and code:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.example.popup.MainActivity$download.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:191)
     at com.example.popup.MainActivity$download.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


class download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                result = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);
                _jarray1 = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i=0;i<_jarray1.length();i++)
                {
                    DataModel datamodel = new DataModel();
                    JSONObject _obj = _jarray1.getJSONObject(i);
                     ImagePath = _obj.getString("imagepath");
                    if (ImagePath != null) {
                        datamodel.setImagepath(_obj.getString("imagepath"));
                    }
                    list.add(datamodel);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, list);
        fruitList.setAdapter(adapter);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `fruitList=null` check it...

Comment: your doInBackground method has return null; and why are you calling super.onPostExecute(result);? there is no need!

Comment: fruitList  is listview  and how i will check it null and also i have remove on onPostExecute(result); how to fix it

Comment: @MD onpostexcute i am getting list null where am doing mistake while i debug in doinbackground am getting data

Comment: You have not initialized fruitList. You  have to use findItemById() on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to attempt android development you should invest some time and effort in reading the google provided documentation. in this case for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Reviewing your code:-

```
class download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

A java class name should start with a capital letter, e.g. Download not download.

You AsyncTask is defined as follows:-

```
Params = Void: the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
Progress = Void: the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
Result = Void: the type of the result of the background computation.
```

This is WRONG! Your code "returns" a list, although your implementation does this with a class variable called `list`. If you are going to use an `AsyncTask` to retrieve data, use `AsyncTask` the way it was designed to work, e.g. return the result from with the `doInbackground()` method. you should define your AsyncTask as follows

```
class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<DataModel>>
```

You should also be checking isCancelled() within your doInBackground method and have defensive coding in the  `protected void onPostExecute(List<DataModel> result) {` to detect when a null result has been received.

When the AsyncTask tasks calling activity is stopped you will need to cancel the AsyncTask, otherwise exceptions will occur. You have no control over when your activity will be stopped, all you have control over is what to do when it is stopped. e.g. when your activity is paused or stopped you will need to call the `AsyncTask` `cancel(boolean)` method.

Just because you have used the same code elsewhere and data is returned doesn't make this code correct. Just because code doesn't fail doesn't make that code correct either.

Comment: what i have to change it please suggest me where am doing mistake and what i need to change coz same code i have used with another service i am able to getd ata